# Jquery trigger.click() on buttons not working sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-events

The requirement is simple on my page, When I click one button I want to automatically click a hidden button.

This is what I am using:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', '#button1', function() {
        //code to display some divs and hide some divs
        $('#button2').trigger('click');
    });
})
```

It is working sometimes and sometimes the button is not clicked. I am not sure what is wrong with this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See this code lines.It works. I see when you use the **IIFE** you don't pass the jQuery object. Or try to compare with your code lines.

```js
(function($) {
  
  $('#button1').on('click', function(){
    console.log('button1');
  });
  
  $('#button2').on('click', function(){
    console.log('button2');
  })
  
$(document).on('click', '#button1', function() {
//code to display some divs and hide some divs
$('#button2').trigger('click');

});
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='button1'>A</button>
<button id='button2'>B</button>
```

Comment: I am not able to check exactly because this is not often seen. Can we check if the trigger click is succesful or not?

Comment: @user168983 No you can't, if you have attached an event and then trigger it, it will always work.

Comment: still facing the issue ...still some times the next button is not clicked automatically

Answer (score -1):

you could also do this

```js
(function($) {
  
  $('#button1').on('click', function(){
    console.log('button1 and button clicked ');
  });
  
  $('#button2').on('click', function(){
    console.log('button2 clicked');
  })
  
$(document).on('click', '#button1', function() {
//code to display some divs and hide some divs
$('#button2').click();

});
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='button1'>clickme btn1</button>
<button id='button2'>clickme btn1</button>
```

Comment: How is different from other answers

Answer (score -1):

You can try this also:

```
 $(function() {
     $('#button1').on('click', function(){
       console.log('button1 clicked ');
     });

     $('#button2').on('click', function(){
       console.log('button2 clicked');
     });

     $('#button1').click(function(){

       $('#button2').click();
     });

  });


  <body>
    <button id='button1'>button1</button>
    <button id='button2'>button2</button>
  </body>
```

Comment: How is different from other answers